# /auditLogs/signIns endpoint reporting I don't have a premium license

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While using the Graph API to collect azure ad auditlogs I'm running into an issue

while issuing a request on the 'auditLogs/signIns' endpoint such as:

'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?%24filter=createdDateTime+ge+2020-10-30T11%3A45%3A27.292054Z+and+createdDateTime+le+2020-10-30T12%3A05%3A27.292053Z'

Sometimes I will be provided the signin data however other times the below error will be returned:

{"error": {"code": "Authentication_RequestFromNonPremiumTenantOrB2CTenant", "message": "Neither tenant is B2C or tenant doesn't have premium license", "innerError": {"date": "2020-11-05T12:09:59", "request-id": "xxxxxx", "client-request-id": "xxxxxxx"}}}

I have check and the azure AD instance I am querying has a "Azure AD Premium P1" license.

To my understanding the '/auditLogs/directoryaudits' endpoint also requires a premium license however I'm currently querying this without issue.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Can you please provide the correlation id and timestamp?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I'm using "List signIns" so not using a correlation id:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
timestamp : I issued the request at 2020-11-05T12:09:59 and the request asked for logs between 2020-10-30T11:45:27.292054Z - 2020-10-30T12:05:27.292053Z

Comment: Can you please provide error message request-id and client-request-id

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity  "request-id": "41cbb5d0-7934-4900-af6b-6430f816d53d", "client-request-id": "41cbb5d0-7934-4900-af6b-6430f816d53d"

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my lab with Azure AD Free subscription for the below queries

[image]

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits
```

The above query working fine with AzureAd free subscription

[image]

But for signIns logs `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signins` you need to have a premium subscription  so please check your Subscription in the portal

[image]

Comment: Thanks as in my first post I have checked and have an Azure AD Premium P1 license. Hence why I made this post I have the correct license however I'm getting an error saying I don't.

Comment: Thank you for your reply can you please raise the Microsoft support ticket to investigate this further